# Can I move the manifest.json file to a folder?

Tags: webpack, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to follow this tutorial [Build Simple Chrome Extension From Scratch Using React, Bootstrap, Babel and Webpack](https://medium.com/@ramez.aijaz/build-simple-chrome-extension-from-scratch-using-react-bootstrap-babel-and-webpack-374f97bdafde), but I received an error: "This extension includes the key pem file".

Searching on Google, I found the following explanation: "***Currently manifest.json is in the root of the project so everything in node_modules directory gets included with the loading of the extension, including the .pem file.***" So I noticed that in the tutorial, the author put the manifest.json on src, so I move it. But then I received this other error [Chrome Extension error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avjtr.png)

I imagine I am doing something wrong, missing some configuration, but I cannot find which one. Anyone knows how can I move the manifest.json file to another folder, so avoiding the file pem issue, but at the same time let Chrome knows where the file it is, so it can be correctly loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer. I was, erroneously, trying to upload the extension folder, when what I need to do was to upload the dist folder. Normally, on a chrome extension, you upload your working folder but adding webpack changes that game